# How to install a tar file

Tags: software-installation, tar

I can't find a program I wanted from the software centre, so had to download a tar file, but it wont install.
Do I have to have a degree in physics or coding just to get it to install?
I can't understand why a mouse click wont start the install process?
I've tried to figure out the 'compile' etc commands, but I can't do it.
Thanks

Comment: tar is short for tarball; a means to install programs in 1979 on very different systems (aix, unix, bsd, ... hp/ux). it's really just a compressed file, which you must expand & follow the enclosed readme (usually a 'make' which explores your system & works out what OS is running, how to install, then 'make install').  It's a good system that is machine independent (works regardless of whether or not you have gui); and the same code we used in 1980 works today.  I like consistency.   have you installed build-essential ?

Comment: Please understand that one of the reasons Ubuntu is so safe is that **we do not usually click on stuff downloaded from the Internet**. For very special software or for testing we may have no other choice than to install from source but this should be exceptional.

Comment: I understand Linux is not intended to be merely "easy" without responsibility. Ramsonwares and other tech-plagues exist due to Windows easiness.

Comment: At least you admit it's not easy. I am tired of these people who say 'it's so easy even my gran uses it'  what utter bs. My parents use windows, which they can usually manage ok. If I they tried to  use linux, they would not have a chance

Comment: And I'm still left staring at a tar file that I cannot install. I think its justified to say Balls to linux

Comment: @Rush: My granny uses Ubuntu and she's happy with it. She calls me more frequently about issues with her Windows system. Then again she doesn't try to install random software off the internet and sticks with what's in the Software Center because here needs don't extend beyond that. Whether Ubuntu/Linux is simple depends on what you want to with it and whether your use case was included in the software design – just like with any other technology.

Comment: The software center doesn't always have the programmes people want to use. I guess your granny does nothing more than surf the web and check emails then. If windows are Linux are set up first, then sure most people can use either system for that - but linux often needs drivers which are often harder to find and install than windows.
For trying to actually do stuff though, Linux is pathetic. 
In windows, more often than not, to do simple things and even semi complex things, a mouse is all you need. You only need to start going into msconfig etc for under the hood stuff.

Comment: I linux, the terminal often has to be used for simple stuff.
This granny analogy is shit anyway at least the way you people use it. It's like saying my granny can sit in a race car so she is a good as Schumaker. Yea, cos she never has to drive the car, just look at a few buttons and press them. If she did actually have to drive it, she would find windows far easier.
The ABSOLUTE proof is in the pudding. It is UNDENIABLE - Linux is FREE! Yet next to nobody uses it. They would rather pay big bucks for windows because it simply works and is usable without having a degree in techno wank.

Answer (score 3):

Mr Rush every in learn has to be given some period to understand it. When installing using a `tar` file we have to follow certain steps to get it installed:

1. Download the `tar` file
2. `Untar` it with `tar -xvf finename.tar`
3. Change into the `untarred` file and inside you will find a `README` file to direct you on how to install the application as was intended or designed by the owners.
4. For `step 3` we may see a simple install script that we may have to make `installable` (depending on whether that has already been done by the creators), from our terminal using the command:

   ```
   chmod u+x install.sh
   ```

   - Note that it can be called anything or even lack a file `extension`
5. But ofcourse the `tar` file can be untarred by `right clicking` on it with your mouse and selecting `Extra here`.

Now to answer your click issue, Ubuntu comes with `.deb` package file that are installed using the mouse click, if you are asked to use a `tar` file then it's the creators fault and not Ubuntu. They were too lazy or busy to create a `.deb` package file. They alone can say why they prefer `tar` file rather than `.deb` files.

Comment: With respect, why is it necessary to study this just ti install something?
I really don't want to learn all that just to do basic things

Comment: Let me finish my answer and you will see that Ubuntu also has click install options

Comment: Thanks
So hopefully we can skip those other steps and just click something and install it.
Because I have difficulty following those other steps, and they definately are not click to instal...

Comment: OK, well I can't install it. The fact that tar files even exist is ubuntus fault anyway. Since there are so many of the damn things, this is not the first time I've come accros this problem
Ubuntu still sucks ass
Always has